# Tree structure whit post request cURL and Json and http login

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, tree

i'm sending a post request with PHP and cURL, the request is a json tree comand.

I have this array

```
$arr = array(
    "lookupKey" => "Ejemplo", 
    "subject" => "Prueba HideBanner", 
    "body" => "Esto es una prueba", 
    "issuerName" => "Karla", 
    "recipient" => array(
        "legalName" => "Tania", 
        "emailAddress" => "taniacomprador@outlook.com",),
     "options" => array("certificationlevel" => "Standard") );
```

The output of

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

is

```
{"lookupKey":"Ejemplo","subject":"Prueba HideBanner","body":"Esto es una prueba","issuerName":"Karla","recipient":"legalName":"Tania","emailAddress":"taniacomprador@outlook.com"},"options":{"certificationlevel":"Standard"}}
```

this is the command I need

but when i run the cURL request with the comand, the server returns

```
{"responseStatus":{"errorCode":"SerializationException","message":"Error deserializing FormData: lookupKey=Ejemplo&subject=Prueba HideBanner&body=Esto es una prueba&issuerName=Karla&recipient=Array&options=Array"}}
```

recipent= Array

options= Array

This is the function

```
    function sendPostData($url, $post){

    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass"; 

    $ch = curl_init($url);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $curlResult = curl_exec($ch);


    //errors check  
    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch) . '<br>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors <br>';
    }

    curl_close($ch); 

  return $curlResult;


}
```

Call to the function

```
$arr = array(
    "lookupKey" => "Ejemplo", 
    "subject" => "Prueba HideBanner", 
    "body" => "Esto es una prueba", 
    "issuerName" => "Karla", 
    "recipient" => array(
        "legalName" => "Tania", 
        "emailAddress" => "taniacomprador@outlook.com", 
        )
    ,"options" => array("certificationlevel" => "Standard") );

$output_assembly->JSON->Data = $arr;
echo json_encode($arr);
$str_data= $arr;
$url_send ="url";

echo " " . sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);
```

**UPDATE**

Is working

```
function sendPostData(){

    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass"; 

    $post = array(
        "lookupKey" => "Ejemplo", 
        "subject" => "Prueba&nbsp;test&nbsp;EviMail", 
        "body" => "&nbsp;mensage", 
        "issuerName" => "demos", 
        "recipient" => array(
            "legalName" => "emailPeticion", 
            "emailAddress" => "mail", 
            )
        ,"options" => array("certificationlevel" => "Standard") );

    $url="url";


    //init curl sesion --------------------------------------
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => getcwd() . '/wp-content/plugins/funciones-evicertia/CAcerts/ecertia.crt',
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($post)
    ));

    $curlResult = curl_exec($ch); 

    curl_close($ch);

    //finish curl sesion --------------------------------------

  return $curlResult;
}
```

Comment: show us the cURL codes.

Comment: Show us the code calling `sendPostData()`

Comment: ok, the post its update

Comment: Why using `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`? Use `CURLOPT_POST` instead.

Comment: It is the same, isn`t it?